# respondToSelector / performSelector with parameter from a string in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, selector, nsobject, performselector, respond-to

I have to call method of a class. This method potentially exists or not.
I'm looking for a solution from 2 hours. 
The following works without parameter `sayHello()`

I have the class :

```
class myClass: NSObject {
    func say(something:String){
        print("I say : \(something)")
    }

    func sayHello(){
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

1st step : Create a selector from a string with a parameter

```
let selector = NSSelectorFromString("sayHello" ) 
let selectorWithParam = NSSelectorFromString("say:" )
```

2nd step : Test if the method exist

```
self.bot?.responds(to: selector)// true
self.bot?.responds(to: selectorWithParam) // false
```

it doesn't work with a parameter!

Beside, i tried with the Swift3 `#selector` , but I found no way to enter a method from a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift method

```
func say(something:String)
```

is mapped to Objective-C as

```
- (void)sayWithSomething:(NSString * _Nonnull)something;
```

and therefore the correct selector would be

```
let selectorWithParam = NSSelectorFromString("sayWithSomething:" )
```

Using `#selector` is less error-prone:

```
let selectorWithParam = #selector(myClass.say(something:))
```

Comment: Thanks you, and how to create a `#selector` from a variable? `let myMethod = "sayWithSomething"`
 The method could be anything and I have to check if it exist before to call it

Comment: @DamienRomito: You cannot use `#selector` with a variable. If you really need to create a selector dynamically from an arbitrary string then you can use only  `NSSelectorFromString`. (It would be interesting to know *why* you need that.)

Comment: The behaviour of my application depends on a customizable json. This  json list methods to call.

Comment: Note that this is potentially dangerous. What if the JSON contains a method  name which happens to be a `NSObject(Protocol)` method (e.g. `release`). Calling that method on the object would cause memory corruption. –Anyway, you asked why your NSSelectorFromString does not work, and I have (hopefully) answered that.

Comment: Yes, the better solution I found is to use a "switch case" to match the variable to the corresponding method. This way, isn't dangerous. Thank you Martin! Good luck for you Stackoverflow's quest ;)