# Implement perform selector with parameter from a String

Tags: ios, swift, string, performselector

I need to implement a perform selector from a String.
The Selector must have as parameter a Notification value.

```
class ChapterViewController: UIViewController {

    var chapterClass:ChapterClass!

    func catchNotificationParagraphFinished(notification:Notification) {

        let name = "catchNotificationParagraphFinished_\(chapter.className!)"
        let selector = NSSelectorFromString(name)

        chapterClass.perform(selector, with: notification)   
    }
}

    class ChapterClass: NSObject {

        func catchNotificationParagraphFinished_Chapter2(notification:Notification) {}
    }
```

I suppose I'm doing something wrong, because I got this error:

> *[ISAMGAME.ChapterClass catchNotificationParagraphFinished_Chapter2]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000052c60*
>
> *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ISAMGAME.ChapterClass
>   catchNotificationParagraphFinished_Chapter2]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x600000052c60**

I also tried with:

```
func catchNotificationParagraphFinished_Chapter2(_ notification:Notification) {}
```

And also tried using:

```
let name = "catchNotificationParagraphFinished_\(chapter.className!):"
let selector = Selector((name))
```

I based my approach thanks to:

- [How to create Selector with parameters from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451683/how-to-create-selector-with-parameters-from-string)
- [respondToSelector / performSelector with parameter from a string in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020999/respondtoselector-performselector-with-parameter-from-a-string-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My method works fine, but don't forget to add String type to the constant...

```
 let name:String = "catchNotificationParagraphFinished_\(chapter.className!):"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to include the parameter name as well as class name in the selector string, therefore the selector string becomes:

```
let name = "ChapterClass.catchNotificationParagraphFinished_\(chapter.className!)(notification:)"
```

Comment: I really need to create my selector from String. Depending of the string, I will call catchNotificationParagraphFinished_Chapter2 or catchNotificationParagraphFinished_Chapter3... etc... I like to avoid to have many "if" conditions.

Comment: Same crash "[ISAMGAME.ChapterClass catchNotificationParagraphFinished_Chapter2(notification:)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" :(

Comment: It could be that you can't perform a selector on a class outside of the current class, therefore try calling a method in ChapterClass that is passed a class name and performs the selector on itself

Comment: It was a good idea, but I have just tried and the same error appears ...